# CLI Twitter client in Python

Tags: python, console, twitter

Here is a simple client for Wwitter that I wrote based on the `twitter` library in Python. The aim is to be able to read the feeds from different twitter accounts from the same place in a light way.

I should mention that the code does what I want it to do. Nevertheless, how could I improve it?

(It is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/bilbopingouin/twicli).)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import os
import getopt
from twitter import *

# Default values
def_counts = 10
users = []
dir_creds = "./data/oauth/"

# input parameters
def usage():
  print "Run: " + sys.argv[0] + " [OPTIONS]"
  print "Where OPTIONS is one the following: "
  print " -h --help"
  print " -c N --counts=N"
  print " -u \"name\" --user=\"name\""
  print " -a --all"
  print " -l --list"

def main(argv):
  global def_counts, users
  try: 
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hc:u:al",["help","counts=","user=","all","list"])
  except getopt.GetoptError:
    usage()
    exit(2)
  for opt,arg in opts:
    if opt in ["-h","--help"]:
      usage()
      exit(1)
    elif opt in ["-c","--counts"]:
      print "Retrieving "+str(arg)+" tweets."
      def_counts = arg
    elif opt in ["-u","--user"]:
      print "User: "+arg
      users.append(arg)
    elif opt in ["-a","--all"]:
      print "all users"
      if os.path.exists(os.path.expanduser(dir_creds)):
        token_files = filter(lambda x: x.endswith('.token'), os.listdir(os.path.expanduser(dir_creds)))
        for file in token_files:
          usr = file[:file.index(".token")]
          users.append(usr)
      else:
        print "No user to be added, path undefined"
        exit(2)
    elif opt in ["-l","--list"]:
      if os.path.exists(os.path.expanduser(dir_creds)):
        token_files = filter(lambda x: x.endswith('.token'), os.listdir(os.path.expanduser(dir_creds)))
        for file in token_files:
          usr = file[:file.index(".token")]
          print usr
    else:
      print "Got the following and I don't know what to do with it:"
      print opt + " " + arg
      usage()
      exit(2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main(sys.argv[1:])

if len(users) < 1:
  users.append("bilbo_pingouin")

col_bgred   = '\033[41m'
col_bold    = '\033[1m'
col_fgblue  = '\033[34m'
col_fggreen = '\033[32m'
col_fggrey  = '\033[90m'
col_end     = '\033[0m'

for user in users:
  print "\n" + col_bgred + col_bold + user + col_end
  # Retrieve the credentials for a given account
  if not os.path.exists(dir_creds):
    os.makedirs(dir_creds) # I just assume there is not race issue here!

  file_creds = dir_creds + user + ".token"
  MY_TWITTER_CREDS = os.path.expanduser(file_creds)

  api_token_file = "data/api_token.dat"
  if os.path.exists(api_token_file):
    cust_token, cust_secret =     read_token_file(os.path.expanduser(api_token_file))
  else:
    print "ERROR: The app is not identified!"

  if not os.path.exists(MY_TWITTER_CREDS):
    oauth_dance("Twit on CLI",cust_token,cust_secret,
            MY_TWITTER_CREDS)

  oauth_token, oauth_secret = read_token_file(MY_TWITTER_CREDS)

  # OAuth idnetification
  t = Twitter(auth=OAuth(oauth_token,oauth_secret,cust_token,cust_secret))

  # Get status
  data = t.statuses.home_timeline(count=def_counts)

  # Print lines
  for c in range(len(data)):
    print "* " + col_fggreen+col_bold+data[c]['user']['name']+col_end + ' (' + col_fgblue+data[c]['user']['screen_name']+col_end + ')' + " - " + data[c]['text'] + col_fggrey+" ## "+data[c]['created_at']+col_end
```

Answer (score 3):

For starters using Python 3 or at least being compatible with it would
be a good idea.  Meaning that all the `print` calls should be using the
function form, i.e. `print(...)`.

Next, take a look at [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)
and use four spaces for indentation.

Parsing command line arguments is a bit nicer with
[`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), but since
you're already done with it it might not make too much sense to rewrite
that part.

There's duplicated for the `"--all"` and `"--list"` cases that would be
better served with a common function.

The colour definitions can be taken from some module, e.g. take a look
at [`termcolor`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/termcolor) or
[`colorama`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama).

Lastly the `for c in range(len(data)):` will always be a pattern that
should be replaced with direct iteration, i.e. `for x in data:`.  The
line is also way to long to read it easily.

Answer (score 3):

First things first, let's look at argparsing here.

Your current argument parsing code is... a mess. Something like:

```
import argparse

def main(argv):
    global def_counts, users
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Twitter app')
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--counts', help='Count of tweets to retrieve.', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-u', '--user', help='Username', required=True)

    parser.add_argument('-a', '--all', help='All Users', required=False)
    parser.add_argument('-l', '--list', help='List', required=True)
```

Allows you much more flexibility in actually reading your arguments. As you might notice this is... much easier to configure than your current parsing. It is also easier for a person such as myself to read.

This allows you [do this for a 'help' option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29293080/1048539) if you have at least 1 required argument and get rid of your `usage` method:

```
try:
    options = parser.parse_args()
except:
    parser.print_help()
    sys.exit(0)
```

If require args are not provided it will throw an exception and print the help (which it will do on `-h` or `-help` or `--foo-nicorn`).

This streamlines your parsing of the args:

```
def_counts = options['counts']
user = options['user']
users.append(user)
```

Note that when making strings the following is much more readable:

```
print "Retrieving {count} tweets.".format(count=def_counts)
print "User: {user}".format(user=user)
```

Especially when you have longer strings, such as at the end of your code, using `format` and the variables as parameters is much more clear.

You might notice the parsing for `list` and `all` are almost identical, with the exception of printing or appending. I rewrote this, using your options again (note that an unprovided arg to argparse is `None` so you can do `if arg:` for checking the argument was provided):

```
if options['all'] or options['list']:
    print "all users"
    if os.path.exists(os.path.expanduser(dir_creds)):
        token_files = filter(lambda x: x.endswith('.token'), os.listdir(os.path.expanduser(dir_creds)))
        for f in token_files:
            usr = f[:f.index(".token")]
            if options['all']:
                users.append(usr)
            else:
                print usr     
    else:
        print "No user to be added, path undefined"
        exit(2)
```

I also changed `file` to `f` as `file` is a keyword in Python.

This removes a fair bit of duplication and also makes reading your logic much less painful.

Everything here should reproduce how your logic parsing your args is currently (full disclaimer: it's Friday night and... no guarantees :-).

For pep8/flake8 you generally want to add spaces after commas, too.